# Can video tag be used in HTML 5 to run mp3 audio file?

Tags: html

I am using audio tag to play mp3 file in HTML 5 , rather i want to use video tag for HTML 5.
Is that possible and how can i do that?

```
<audio class="audio" id="c_step_1_audio" controls preload="none" style="display: none"> 
     <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I want to do as follows

```
<video class="audio" id="c_step_1_audio" controls preload="none" style="display: none"> 
   <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</video>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is neither recommended nor approved in any browser or W3C. But try it, might work some where if you are lucky.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support audio in video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: In HTML's spirit parent tags have not that kind of control on child's nature. As `source` tag is correct in every way it should be acceptable in every browser. THOUGH IT IS SEMANTICALY NOT THE CORRECT WAY you may use it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think @XIMRX's answer is correct (anymore?). I've just tried putting audio in a video tag, and video in an audio tag, and both work fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Also, @Kaiido is a pretty authoritative source for web standards in my experience, and [he says it's a browser standard at this point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73480546/11950764), so I don't think it's by coincidence that this works.

Comment: Yes, I have tested and get the same result, it plays whatever you put it. This makes sense because humans always make mistakes, HTML/Javascript can contain errors. So given the media file, there is no point arguing whether it is specified as mp4 or mp3 or mkv or etc., just play it if the browser can. Very simple ^_^ 
Many media players even do this, even if you rename the extension from mp3 to mp4 or vice versa, or rename mp4 into mkv, etc. it always get played.