# Audio in HTML5 Video tag

Tags: html, html5-video

I noticed that using an audio file in `<video>` works fine.

Does this feature have good browser compatibility and is it an HTML5 standard?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374370/will-it-always-be-possible-to-play-an-audio-file-with-the-html5-video-tag) but it's from 7 years ago and has no answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes a `<video>` element is supposed to be able to play media resources that only contain audio data, just like an `<audio>` element is supposed to be able to play video media (without displaying the video stream).
A browser that wouldn't do that would be a buggy browser.

Answer (score 1):

`<video>` tag supports most browsers like chrome, edge, firefox, safari, and opera.

It is a global attribute in HTML5.

For Audio you can also use `<audio>`.

If you want to know more there is something you can check out
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp